# containstable not returning expected results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sql table of products with one value of title 'Beko EV7100'
when i search for 7100 this row is not in my search results
when i search for EV7100 it is ok
What am i doing wrong?
you may see the query below

```
SELECT *, ft.[Rank]
FROM [dbo].[STORE_PRODUCTS] AS sp with(nolock) 
INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE([STORE_PRODUCTS], ( title,[short_description],[long_description]/*,permalink_url*/,meta_keywords), 
ISABOUT ('+@fixed_query+', title WEIGHT(0.4), short_description WEIGHT(0.2),long_description WEIGHT(0.2), permalink_url WEIGHT(0.1), meta_keywords  WEIGHT(0.1)) ) AS ft
ON ft.[key] = sp.id     
and ft.[Rank] > 5
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (Some product specific SQL there.)

Comment: Can you post the sample data from your columns for this entry? What is stored in `title`, `short_description`, `long_description` etc. ?

Comment: title = ''Beko EV7100"

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu 
What is the right way to do that?

Comment: @YosiHavia I'm not sure since I haven't tested, but can you try replacing `CONTAINSTABLE` with `FREETEXTTABLE`? You might have a chance to get the result you want. There is also `SEMANTICSIMILARITYTABLE`, but I have never used it before. [Documentation here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492218.aspx)

Comment: FREETEXTTABLE not return the expected result
SEMANTICSIMILARITYTABLE return error
Do you have any recommendation for a diffrent approach to use search on products in my sql server db?